# TTL not working properly when worked on upsert function in mongodb using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ttl

Hi i came across one concept called as ttl in mongodb and tried the same in a insert operation using mongoose.Below is the code

```
mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var META_CTS_DB = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/META');
var ttl= require('mongoose-ttl');
var date1=new Date();
var ServiceSchema = new Schema({
_id:String, 
CURDATE:{type:Date,index:true},
SERVICE_PROTOCOL:String, 
});
ServiceSchema.plugin(ttl, { ttl:5000 });
var MasterDBdata = META.model('ServiceSchema',ServiceSchema,'API_KEY_91994094177912_SERVICE_ID_0008_SERVICE_CONFIG');
var item = new MasterDBdata({'_id':'SERVICE_ID_0006','CURDATE':date1,'SERVICE_PROTOCOL':'Nil'});
item.save();
```

The ttl worked fine for this and the collection did get deleted.But when i performed the same for a update function as below

```
MasterDBdata.update({'_id':'SERVICE_ID_0006'},{'CURDATE':date1,'SERVICE_PROTOCOL':'hhl'},{upsert:true},function (err){

                                                        if (err) return handleError(err);
                                                        console.log('\n data stored in Database...')});
```

The ttl function didnt seem to work properly.Any idea regarding the behaviour of ttl and its performance on these functions will be really helpful.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The `mongoose-ttl` plug-in uses its own hidden `__ttl` field to track a document's expiration time, so updating your own `CURDATE` field isn't going to have any effect.

If you're on MongoDB 2.2 you should be using the native support for TTL collections instead of the plug-in, defining `CURDATE` as the `expires` key field as discussed in your previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14597622/1259510).

Comment: I tried the following example                                       var schema = new Schema({ createdAt: Date });
schema.path('createdAt').expires('5s'); Bu I got error as follows      schema.path('createdAt').expires('5s');
                                ^
TypeError: Object #<SchemaDate> has no method 'expires'.Any idea regarding this will be helpful

Comment: @AmandaG What version of Mongoose are you using?  Run `npm update mongoose` to update to the latest as this is a fairly recent addition.