# Time to live in mongodb, mongoose dont work. Documents doesnt get deleted

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Im using this scheme for a session in my node.js app

```
var mongoose     = require('mongoose');
var Schema       = mongoose.Schema;
// define the schema for our user session model
var UserSessionSchema   = new Schema({
    sessionActivity:    { type: Date, expires: '15s' }, // Expire after 15 s
    user_token:         { type: String, required: true }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('UserSession', UserSessionSchema);
```

And I create a "session" in my app with:

```
...
var session = new Session();
session.user_token = profile.token;
session.save(function(save_err) {
    if (save_err) {
        ....
    } else {
        // store session id in profile
        profile.session_key = session._id;
        profile.save(function(save_err, profile) {
            if (save_err) {
                ...
            } else {
                res.json({ status: 'OK', session_id: profile.session_id });
            }
});
...
```

The problem is that the document lives permanetly, its never expires. It should only live for 15 seconds (up to a minute). Whats wrong with my code? I have tried to set the expries: string to a number i.e 15, to a string '15s' and so on.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting expiry time for a collection in mongodb using mongoose](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14597241/setting-expiry-time-for-a-collection-in-mongodb-using-mongoose)

Comment: TTL indexes require a integer for seconds till expiry and not a string. The process is also run every minute. So that can take up to one minute from expiry time.

Comment: I have tried with setting the expires property with a number. I have read that question Christian, but I dont really get the note: "It's up to you to set createdAt to the current time when creating docs." Do I need to set createdAt to Date.now() or something like that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var UserSessionSchema   = new Schema({
    sessionActivity:    { type: Date, expires: '15s', default: Date.now }, // Expire after 15 s
    user_token:         { type: String, required: true }
});
```

A TTL index deletes a document 'x' seconds after its value (which should be a Date or an array of Dates) has passed. The TTL is checked every minute, so it may live a little longer than your given 15 seconds.

To give the date a default value, you can use the `default` option in Mongoose. It accepts a function. In this case, `Date()` returns the current timestamp. This will set the date to the current time *once*.

You could also go this route:

```
UserSessionSchema.pre("save", function(next) { 
    this.sessionActivity = new Date(); 
    next(); 
});
```

This will update the value *every time* you call `.save()` (but not `.update()`).

Comment: Thank you, but I cant this to work, The documents get deleted after a long time, but not in 15secs (or in about a minute). If I run ISODate() to get the local time in the shell i get "ISODate("2014-06-03T09:55:35.473Z")" but the document still exists. If I check the document I can see that "sessionActivity" has the value ISODate("2014-06-03T09:49:57.977Z"). It should have been deleted several minutes ago.

Comment: What's the output of `db.usersessions.getIndexes()` in the mongo shell? (You might need to correct the collection name). There should be an entry like `{"key": {"sessionActivity": 1} "expireAfterSeconds": <some value>}`

Comment: > db.usersessions.getIndexes()
[
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                },
                "name" : "_id_",
                "ns" : "aquamoto.usersessions"
        },
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "sessionActivity" : 1
                },
                "name" : "sessionActivity_1",
                "ns" : "aquamoto.usersessions",
                "expireAfterSeconds" : 15,
                "background" : true
        }
]
>

Comment: Now it works! { type: Date, expires: '15s', default: Date } didnt work, but UserSessionSchema.pre("save", function(next) { 
    this.sessionActivity = new Date(); 
    next(); 
}); with { type: Date, expires: 15 } works!!! Dont know why but it works :)

Comment: `default: Date` works fine for me, but it seems that most examples advocate `default: Date.now`. The first (`Date()`) will return a string which is then cast to a `Date` object, the second (`Date.now()`) a UNIX timestamp which is cast to a `Date` object in a more fool-proof way. Perhaps locale settings interfere in some way in the first form. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: You missed the ( ) after Date.now( ) in your answer.

Comment: Actually, I didn't. The value `Date.now` is a function, which means that Mongoose will run that function every time it needs a default value. If you were to add brackets, (`default: Date.now()}`), then the value would be evaluated once and it would always be the same date (more specifically: the time when you started your script).

Answer (score 0):

To double check the indexes that have been created in the DB you can run this command in your mongo shell `db.yourdb.getIndexes()`. When changing the indexes you have to manually delete it in the collection before the new one will take effect.  Check here for more information [Mongoose expires property not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29525010/mongoose-expires-property-not-working-properly)