# Mongodb, mongoose - dynamically set TTL time

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am referring to this [Time to live in mongodb, mongoose dont work. Documents doesnt get deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24008956/time-to-live-in-mongodb-mongoose-dont-work-documents-doesnt-get-deleted) to ask my question:
Is it possible to set TTL time for MongoDB dynamically?
So let's suppose you have token collection and you want to use it for different purposes. In that case every time when you create the token it would be nice to set specific TTL for each token.
If this is possible, could you please provide some code snippet?

Comment: Yes. See [Expire Documents at a Certain Clock Time](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/#expire-documents-at-a-certain-clock-time). You have to set the TTL field value to the time when the token should expire. It doesn't, strictly speaking, set a dynamic TTL but it behaves in exactly the same way.

Answer (score 7):

To dynamically set a TTL to a document you can make use of the same index, but create another field like `expireAt` in the schema like:

```
expireAt: {
            type: Date,
            default: null,
}
```

Then create an index like (example for mongoose):

```
schema.index({ expireAt: 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 0 });
```

Now for all documents that you want to expire, you can set the exact datetime. For others, whose field `expireAt` is defaulting to `null` won't expire.

You can see the same example [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/#expire-documents-at-a-specific-clock-time) in MongoDB Docs.

Comment: I am looking for similar kind of solution, but this index will be applied to all documents in same collection, isn't it ? How can we apply different TTL to different documents in same collection ? is there a way or possibility in Mongo DB ?
or the other way round, can i change TTL twice every one hour with different TTL assuming I maintain only one document in complete collection ?

Answer (score 1):

```
If you define a TTL index on a collection, then periodically MongoDB will remove() old documents from the collection.

db.events.ensureIndex('time', expireAfterSeconds=3600)
```

It use an indexing system for handling TTL. Its fixed, there is no way to define it dynamically for each document. in your scenario I recommend you to use Messaging System like RabbitMQ along with MongoDB
https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html