# How can I set the TTL date on document creation in Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to make a `promoCode` schema in Mongoose. On creation, I need to be able to set the promo code's expiration date. Promo codes do not necessarily have the same `TTL`. I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14597241/setting-expiry-time-for-a-collection-in-mongodb-using-mongoose), but my documents still aren't expiring.

This is my `promoCode.js` file:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var promoCodeSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    expirationDate: Date,
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        expireAfterSeconds: Number,
        default: Date.now
    }
})
module.exports = mongoose.model("Promo", promoCodeSchema);
```

Now, in `routes.js`, I have:

```
app.post("/admin/promo/create", isLoggedIn, isVerified, isAdmin, function (req, res) {
    var promo = new Promo();
    promo.createdAt.expireAfterSeconds = 60;
    // for reference, note the actual day on which the promo code should expire
    var days = parseInt(req.body.expiration.replace(/[^\d]+/g, "")) || 1;
    promo.expirationDate = new Date(Date.now() + (days * 24 * 3600 * 1000));

    promo.save(function (err) {
        console.log(err, promo);
        return res.redirect("/admin/promo");
    });
})
```

This doesn't work. I also need to be able to get the value of `TTL`. How would I go about solving this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting expiry time for a collection in mongodb using mongoose](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14597241/setting-expiry-time-for-a-collection-in-mongodb-using-mongoose)

Comment: @royhowie nice question... did you find anything useful in learning mongoose and mean stack in general. From your profile i can see that you and i share lots of things.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer really learn how to properly use callbacks (i.e., how to write your own with error propagation/etc) and how to use helper libraries like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) (or you can go the promises route with [q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q)). Always roll with [express](http://expressjs.com). [lodash](https://lodash.com) or [underscore](http://underscorejs.org) are also always useful (but not necessary)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you want to use different TTL values for each doc, you can use an `expires` time of 0 on a field that contains the expiration timestamp (as described [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/#expire-documents-at-a-certain-clock-time)) and then set that timestamp to reflect your desired TTL for each doc.

You're already computing `expirationDate` in your schema, so you'd want to put your TTL index on that field instead of `createdDate`.  But you need to use `expires` in the definition, not `expiresAtSeconds` like you're using:

```
var promoCodeSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    expirationDate: {
        type: Date,
        expires: 0
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});
```

And then in `routes.js` you only need to set `expirationDate` on the new `Promo` docs to its expiration timestamp (like you're already doing).