# How to remove a record via expiry using a specific date?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

In `mongoose` I can set the expiration of a document defining a column in this way:

```
expire_at: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
    expires: 7200
}
```

The code above will remove the record within two hours.
How can I set the `expire_at` to a specific date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set expires property readable string values like this:

For 1 minute:

```
 expires: "1m"
```

For 1 hour:

```
 expires: "1h"
```

For 1 day:

```
 expires: "1d"
```

But if you want to set a specific date, you can set the expires property 0, and set a date value to the field which has the TTL index as described in mongodb [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/#expire-documents-at-a-certain-clock-time).

Comment: Yes, I can try, but how can I pass the expires parameter? I mean, when I create the object, ec: `let c = CarModel({expire_at: ???})` what I need to pass as value? thanks

Comment: @sfarzoso hmm, it is not field but property, so I guess it is not possible to set a value from outside.

Comment: @sfarzoso I just guess like that, I am not sure. By the way there is also another option like this:  default: () => new Date(+new Date() + 3 * 60 * 1000) //3 minutes

Comment: @sfarzoso maybe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59237955/how-to-remove-unverified-user-with-mongoose-and-ttl) also help a little.

Comment: @sfarzoso look what I found, it seems it is possible. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24275117/how-can-i-set-the-ttl-date-on-document-creation-in-mongoose