# How do I set a document to expire using Mongoose (Node.js)?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have created the following document schema :

```
var mongoose = require('./node_modules/mongoose');
mongoose.connect(mongodburi, {
    server : {
        socketOptions : {
            keepAlive: 1
        }
    },
    replset : {
        socketOptions : {
            keepAlive: 1
        }
    }
});
var sessionSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    uid: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    token: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
        unique: true
    }
});

var Session = mongoose.model('Session', sessionSchema);
```

I use the above to create/add documents to my  Mongo DB like so :

```
var session = new Session();
session.uid = getUniqueID();
session.token = getToken();
session.save(function (err, session)
{
    if (session.uid && session.uid.length) console.log('new doc saved');
    else console.log('failed to save new doc');
});
```

Whenever I create a document I want it to automatically expire (i.e. get deleted from the database) 24 hours after the moment it was created.

How do I do that ?

I found [a somewhat relevant post in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14597241/setting-expiry-time-for-a-collection-in-mongodb-using-mongoose) but apparently it's about expiring *collections* whereas I'm interested in expiring *documents*, not collections *of* documents.

If this question has indeed already been answered by the above post please feel free to delete it to avoid clutter. I have created [a new question about resetting the expiration date of a document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33844643/how-do-i-reset-the-expiration-date-of-a-document-in-mongoose-node-js) (to which I found no answer on SO)

Comment: The answer you linked to is what you want. You'd add a `createdAt` field to your schema to support it the expiration of your docs.

Comment: And this will only expire that document and not the whole collection, right ?

Comment: Yep, documents are individually expired based on the `createdAt` value in each document.

Comment: Thanks! Any thoughts on this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33844643/how-do-i-reset-the-expiration-date-of-a-document-in-mongoose-node-js ?