# How do I reset the expiration date of a document in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Based on the answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14597241/setting-expiry-time-for-a-collection-in-mongodb-using-mongoose) I have created the following document schema, which sets every new document created to expire 24 hours after its creation :

```
var mongoose = require('./node_modules/mongoose');
mongoose.connect(mongodburi, {
    server : {
        socketOptions : {
            keepAlive: 1
        }
    },
    replset : {
        socketOptions : {
            keepAlive: 1
        }
    }
});
var sessionSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    uid: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    token: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
        unique: true
    },
    createdAt: { 
        type: Date, 
        default: Date.now,
        expires: 24*60*60
    }
});

var Session = mongoose.model('Session', sessionSchema);
```

I want to be able to reset the expiration of a document for another 24 hours. Is this the way to do it (?) :

```
Session.update({uid: someUID}, {createdAt: Date.now}, null, function (err, numOfSessionsUpdated)
{
   if (numOfSessionsUpdated > 0)
   {
      console.log('session expiration has been postponed for another 24 hours');
   }    
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's close, but you need to *call* `Date.now` instead of just passing it as that's a function:

```
Session.update({uid: someUID}, {createdAt: Date.now()}, null, function (err, numOfSessionsUpdated)
{
   if (numOfSessionsUpdated > 0)
   {
      console.log('session expiration has been postponed for another 24 hours');
   }    
});
```

Comment: I see, thanks!. I was confused because in the Schema constructor you don't call that function (for the `createdAt` key), but I assume that's because, in the schema constructor, you simply indicate what function needs to be called when the time comes for a new doc to be created.