# Mongo DB document is not deleting after it expires

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to set up a model so that when a table get added, it will have an expiration date, after it expires, the table will delete itself. I tried implementing it like this:

```
expires: '1m'
```

and with

```
expires: 10
```

I have a table set up like the following:

```
const verifySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _userId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    hash: { type: String, required: true },
    createdAt: { type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now, expires: '1m' }
});
```

The problem is, nothing happens after the minute. It doesn't get deleted in the database. Am I doing anything wrong?

How can I delete a table after a minute?

Comment: I'm not sure the `1m` shorthand works. Try setting 1 minute in seconds as `expires: 60`.

Comment: Also look at this question/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14597241/1861779

Comment: Note: you may need to drop the index before changing the `expires` attribute: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/#restrictions

Comment: Remove your index and re-create it again. Code looks good. `expires: '1m'` works but remember that the TTL process runs once every 60 seconds so it is not perfectly on time always. I just tested it and it works as expected with `2m` etc.

Comment: @t.888 Can you please explain what you mean by dropping the index? Also, I didn't change the expire attribute. It's whatever the default value is, and I never change it. Am I supposed to change it?

Comment: @Steve, setting `expires` creates a TTL index on the collection defined by your schema; see here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/. You can try deleting that index using the MongoDB shell or MongoDB Compass: https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass. It's worth trying to delete that index and then restarting your application so that mongoose will recreate the index with the desired TTL (`expires: 60`).

Comment: @t.888 I tried deleting it and restarting mongod. The new ones still don't get removed. I waiting a decent amount of time. Do you mind posting a working example

Comment: And sorry for the horrible Grammer... On the mobile version. Lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a working sample using `mongoose v5.5.9`. It turns out the missing part is the schema entry `index: { expires: '1m' }` in the `createdAt` field.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
// $ npm install uuid
const uuid = require('uuid')

const ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId

// Avoid deprecation warnings
mongoose.set('useNewUrlParser', true);
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);

// Create the schema.
const verifySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _userId: {
      type: ObjectId,
      required: true,
      ref: 'User'
  },

  hash: { type: String, required: true },

  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    required: true,
    default: Date.now,
    index: { expires: '1m' }
  }
},
{
  collection: 'verify'
});

// Connect to mongodb.
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test').then(() => {
  // Create the model
  const Verify = mongoose.model('Verify', verifySchema)

  // Create a model instance.
  const v = new Verify({
    _userId: new ObjectId(),
    hash: uuid.v4()
  })

  // Save the model.
  v.save().then(() => {
    // Close the connection.
    mongoose.connection.close()
  })
})
```

You can check your indexes with [MongoDB Compass](https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass), or using the shell:

```
> use test
> db.verify.getIndexes()
```

Look for the field value `expireAfterSeconds` which will indicate the TTL time in seconds that is set for the index. In order to change the TTL, you will need to drop the index on `createdAt`. In the shell, the command would be `db.verify.dropIndex(<index_name>)` or `db.verify.dropIndexes()` to drop all indexes on the collection.

For upserting documents, such as with [findOneAndUpdate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate), you will need to pass `setDefaultsOnInsert: true` to the options like so:

```
// Connect to mongodb.
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test').then(() => {
  // Create the model
  const Verify = mongoose.model('Verify', verifySchema)

  const _userId = new ObjectId()
  const hash = uuid.v4()
  const options = { upsert: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true }

  // Upsert the document.
  Verify.findOneAndUpdate( { _userId }, { hash }, options).then(() => {
    mongoose.connection.close()
  })
})
```

This is necessary or else the `createdAt` field, which contains the TTL index, won't get added to the document.

Comment: When I do this it doesn't remove itself after the expiration date.
`const verify = await Verify.findOneAndUpdate(
  { _userId: user._id },
  { hash: uuidv4() },
  { upsert: true, new: true }
 );`

Comment: @Steve The problem appears to be that the `createdAt` field doesn't get set by default with that command, so the TTL index isn't on the new document. Add `setDefaultsOnInsert: true` to the options and it should work: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate

Comment: I've updated the answer to contain an explanation for `findOneAndUpdate` behavior.

Comment: Thank you very much @t.888 for your help!!!!! Really appreciate it, and definitely learned a lot!!

Comment: My pleasure, @Steve, glad I could help!

Comment: `setDefaultsOnInsert: true` for upserting was what I was missing, thanks