# Mongoose "expires" deletes document too quick

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, ttl

I'm trying to create auto-expiring Mongoose document by setting `expires`.

```
const mySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   title: {
      type: String,
      required: true
   },
   content: {
      type: String,
      required: true
   },
   expireAt: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now,
      index: { expires: 1200 } // Delete after 20 minutes.
   }
}, { collection: 'mycollection', timestamps: true });
```

I want it to terminate after **20 minutes** but it keeps on terminating after about 1 - 2 minutes.

I've tried `{ expires: '20m' }` as well which also deletes document after about 1 - 2 minutes.

Comment: @goto1 I already tried ```20m``` format and same result. And I don't think it's in ms. Check this blog's step 2: https://dev.to/christopherliedtke/how-to-verify-your-users-email-addresses-node-js-express-dg0

Comment: Have you tried looking at this? [Setting expiry time for a collection in mongodb using mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14597241/setting-expiry-time-for-a-collection-in-mongodb-using-mongoose)

Comment: @goto1 Yes, I already did. They syntax I'm using will create same format. https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema-index

Comment: if you already created the index in this collection, you need to drop the index and recreate it in order for a "new/updated" expireAt index to take effect.

Comment: @krisfremen When I do ```console.log(mySchema.indexes());``` to see indexes, it logs this: ```[ { expireAt: 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 1200, background: true } ]```.

Comment: strange, then it should work, the only thing I can think of.. if you are inserting the documents with a wrong time zone. Date.now() should give UTC time, but if your computer clock isn't set up correctly, this might put it in the future and mongod will delete these records in the next expiry batch.

Comment: @krisfremen I read many different blogs, documents, etc but I'm unable to fix it :(. I'm in EST timezone and my Mongodb outputs UTC. I also tried large time like ```1200000``` instead of ```1200``` and also ```'20m'``` format and all are deleting in 2 minutes. What do you mean by _'put it in the future and mongod will delete these records in the next expiry batch'_?

Comment: yep, same problem document expire too quick even with large expiry, anyone have fix ?