# Mongoose/mongodb expire time/TTL not working .... whats wrong with my code?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, ttl

Though I set expiration time  , but still, data was not deleted from MongoDB .How can I solve this ? or what is wrong with my code .....?

my `mongoose` version `6.1.2`

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const AccessTokenSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    email:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    token:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
        index: { expires: '3m' }
    }
},{
    versionKey: false,
})

const AccessTokenModel = mongoose.model('AccessToken',AccessTokenSchema)

module.exports = AccessTokenModel
```

[Data in mongodb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYI76.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting expiry time for a collection in mongodb using mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14597241/setting-expiry-time-for-a-collection-in-mongodb-using-mongoose)

Comment: The problem is same the but that solution not working for me...

Comment: Does the createdAt field actually have a value for all documents?  Did you verify the index was created?

Comment: @Joe yes. in createAt field have a value of creating each date creating time .  here is a database screenshot  .  **[schreenshort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYI76.png)**

Comment: the version of your mongodb?

Comment: @MarcoBertelli , I use mongoose here...behind the seen mongoose use MongoDB , but I think that's why no need to install MongoDB directly.Is there any need to install MongoDB ?

Comment: sure, mongoose have a basic deps that automatically install mongoDB

Comment: but into the db what is the version?

Comment: @MarcoBertelli , sorry to say that , in my package.json I am not found the MongoDB version. here is my package.json file  [screenshort](https://prnt.sc/245fzif)   .  I am connected to MongoDB with mongoURI with mongoose . And my connected MongoDB version is 4.4.10 . But I am not install MongoDB in my project .

Comment: Steps to troubleshoot: connect directly to the mongod with compass or a shell, make sure an index exists with the expireAfterSeconds option, then make sure the TTL monitor is enabled, and has a reasonable interval set.