# is there any way to delete old documents in mongoDB using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

hey i need to delete old documents in a collection in mongoDB using mongoose package I'm currently using `mongoose` version `6.4.0` and `mongoDB` version `v5.0.5-rc0` and i have tried all answers given bellow in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14597241/setting-expiry-time-for-a-collection-in-mongodb-using-mongoose)

i need to know if there any way to full fill my requirement using mongoose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your schema of course, but a general structure of an invoked `mongoose` is:

```js
const doDelete = async () => {
  var response = await Model.deleteMany({some_parameter:"some_value"});
}

doDelete();
```

You can modify the query parameter delete before a certain date:

```js
const doBeforeDateDelete = async () => {
  var response1 = await Model.deleteMany({createdAt:{"$lt": new Date(2022, 8, 15) }});
}

doBeforeDateDelete();
```

Comment: i asked about ttl index