# MongoDB ttl does not work properly with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to delete entries after e.g. 24 hours, but the entries are already deleted after 2 minutes.

I do the whole thing via mongoose schema.

I use nodejs with mongoose.

```js
const expTime = 24 * 60 * 60;

const schema = new Schema({
    a: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    b: {
        type: String
    }
}, { timestamps: true });

schema.index({ createdAt: 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: expTime });
const model = mongoose.model("example", schema);


//...
model.create({ a, b, "createdAt": new Date() })
    .then(//...)
    .catch((e) => {
        console.error(e);
        //...
    });
```

This is the output when I query the data every minute

```json
10:34:05 AM {a: '...', b: '...', createdAt: '2023-03-09T09:34:05.314Z', updatedAt: '2023-03-09T09:34:05.425Z'}

10:35:00 AM {a: '...', b: '...', createdAt: '2023-03-09T09:34:05.314Z', updatedAt: '2023-03-09T09:34:05.425Z'}

10:36:00 AM {a: '...', b: '...', createdAt: '2023-03-09T09:34:05.314Z', updatedAt: '2023-03-09T09:34:05.425Z'}

10:37:00 AM undefined
```

The same happens when I set the ttl to only 5 minutes.

Can someone tell me why this is not deleted after 24 hours?

I have already tried all possible solutions, without any of them working :/

for example these: [Setting expiry time for a collection in mongodb using mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14597241/setting-expiry-time-for-a-collection-in-mongodb-using-mongoose)

I use

- mongo 6.0.4
- node 19.7.0
- - mongoose 7.0.1

## Edit

By testing the wrong ttl was deposited

`db.getCollection("example").getIndexes().filter(x => x.expireAfterSeconds)`

returned:

```json
[
  {
    v: 2,
    key: { expireAt: 1 },
    name: 'expireAt_1',
    background: true,
    expireAfterSeconds: 300
  },
  {
    v: 2,
    key: { createdAt: 1 },
    name: 'createdAt_1',
    background: true,
    expireAfterSeconds: 120
  }
]
```

After I have set up the database again it is correct

```json
[
  {
    v: 2,
    key: { createdAt: 1 },
    name: 'createdAt_1',
    background: true,
    expireAfterSeconds: 86400
  }
]
```

Comment: What do you get from `db.getCollection("example").getIndexes().filter(x => x.expireAfterSeconds)`?

Comment: [
  {
    v: 2,
    key: { expireAt: 1 },
    name: 'expireAt_1',
    background: true,
    expireAfterSeconds: 300
  },
  {
    v: 2,
    key: { createdAt: 1 },
    name: 'createdAt_1',
    background: true,
    expireAfterSeconds: 120
  }
]

Comment: Oh ok, I have set up the container again, now the ttl is also correct. Thank you