# mongoose / ttl index not deleting documents / mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, next.js

mongodb (mongoose) does not automatically delete documents.

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:String,
}, { timestamps: true })
UserSchema.index({ createdAt: 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 60 });
```

**"timestamps: true"** creates a date. No time zone specified.

createdAt : 2023-04-03T10:07:26.057+00:00

updatedAt : 2023-04-03T10:07:26.057+00:00

[image]

**"UserSchema.index({ createdAt: 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 60 })"** creates an index that should delete the document with the field "createdAt" 60 seconds after creation

[image]

The document is not deleted. I've been in pain all day.

I think that either the ttl timer is not working, or the problem is due to the time zone. I don't know

Comment: Hi, this may be similar to your issue, maybe take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14597241/setting-expiry-time-for-a-collection-in-mongodb-using-mongoose

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting expiry time for a collection in mongodb using mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14597241/setting-expiry-time-for-a-collection-in-mongodb-using-mongoose)